# Can we can configure grpc_pass and proxy_pass on single nginx conf for the same location(/)?

Tags: nginx, proxy, grpc, percona, pmm-server

I am trying to configure Percona PMM along with my proxy servers so that my client servers can securely connect to PMM server. [Attaching the current setup here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0poW.jpg)

Also providing the nginx conf I am using now.

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;

server_name proxy_domain.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate.key;



location / {

grpc_pass grpcs://PMM_serverIP:443;


}

}
```

I can't access the grfana which should be work when I call proxy_domain.com(but now it is redirecting to PMM_serverIP:443) as per the above nginx conf.

I use port 9116 for accessing the grafana by using an additional conf that is given below.

```
server {
    listen 9116 ssl http2;

    server_name proxy_domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
    location / {
    proxy_pass https://PMM_serverIP:443/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }

    }
```

Can I use grpc_pass and proxy_pass for location " / " ? I tried but I can't do that. Also, I tried adding separate configs for grpc_pass and proxy_pass but the server_name conflicts. I want a secure connection using my certs. I also tried grpc_certificate for securing grpc. But still, it is just redirecting to the PMM server IP.